# How to read property data annotation value in .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I Just starting out w/ ASP.NET MVC 3 and I am trying to render out the following HTML for the string properties on a ViewModel on the create/edit view.

```
<input id="PatientID" name="PatientID" placeholder="Patient ID" type="text" value="" maxlength="30" />
```

Each value ties back to the property on the ViewModel, id & name are the property name, placeholder is the Display attribute, value is the value of the property, and maxlength is the StringLength attribute.

Instead of typing out the above HTML w/ the correct values for each of my string properties I thought I would try to create an EditorTemplate by the name of SingleLineTextBox and use UIHint on my string properties or pass the name of the view when I call EditFor. So far so good, except I can't figure out how to get the maxlength value off the StringLength attribute.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<input id="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" name="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" placeholder="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName" type="text" value="@ViewData.Model" maxlength="??" />
```

As you can see, not sure how to set maxlength value. Anyone know how?

Also, am I going about this the best way? As I said before I could just write out the plain HTML myself for each property on the page. I've looked at using TextBoxFor it wasn't setting the maxlength and was adding a bunch of validation markup to the HTML output because of the StringLength attribute which I do not want. Another option I saw was extensions/helpers off the HTML class.

Comment: I would suggest trying to work within the framework rather than against it.  It will make it easier if you use the existing helpers and validation framework than if you try to reinvent your own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of the `StringLength` attribute (because it's a validator attribute not a metadata provider) you can use the `AdditionalMetadata` attribute. Sample usage:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [AdditionalMetadata("maxLength", 30)]
    public string Property { get; set; }
}
```

Basically it puts the value 30 under the key maxLength in the `ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues` dictionary. So you can use it your EditorTemplate:

```
<input maxlength="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["maxLength"]" id="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" name="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" placeholder="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.DisplayName" type="text" value="@ViewData.Model"  />
```

Comment: Another, perhaps better, alternative would be to provide your own ModelMetadataProvider that pulls this value directly from the StringLengthAttribute and puts it in the AdditionalValues dictionary.  It shouldn't take too much to extend the existing one to do this.

Answer (score 8):

A full code sample for tvanfosson's answer:

Model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

EditorTemplates\String.cshtml

```
@model System.String
@{
    var metadata = ViewData.ModelMetadata;
    var prop = metadata.ContainerType.GetProperty(metadata.PropertyName);
    var attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false);

    var maxLength = attrs.OfType<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLengthAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
}
<input id=@Html.IdForModel()@(metadata.IsRequired ? " required" : "")@(maxLength == null ? "" : " maxlength=" + maxLength.Length) />
```

HTML output:

```
<input id=Name maxlength=200 />
```

Ugly but it works. Now let's abstract it and clean it up a bit. Helper class:

```
public static class EditorTemplateHelper
{
    public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo(ViewDataDictionary viewData)
    {
        var metadata = viewData.ModelMetadata;
        var prop = metadata.ContainerType.GetProperty(metadata.PropertyName);
        return prop;
    }

    public static object[] GetAttributes(ViewDataDictionary viewData)
    {
        var prop = GetPropertyInfo(viewData);
        var attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false);
        return attrs;
    }

    public static string GenerateAttributeHtml(ViewDataDictionary viewData, IEnumerable<Delegate> attributeTemplates)
    {
        var attributeMap = attributeTemplates.ToDictionary(t => t.Method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType, t => t);
        var attrs = GetAttributes(viewData);

        var htmlAttrs = attrs.Where(a => attributeMap.ContainsKey(a.GetType()))
            .Select(a => attributeMap[a.GetType()].DynamicInvoke(a));

        string s = String.Join(" ", htmlAttrs);
        return s;
    }
}
```

Editor Template:

```
@model System.String
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
@using Brass9.Web.Mvc.EditorTemplateHelpers;
@{
    var metadata = ViewData.ModelMetadata;

    var attrs = EditorTemplateHelper.GenerateAttributes(ViewData, new Delegate[] {
        new Func<StringLengthAttribute, string>(len => "maxlength=" + len.MaximumLength),
        new Func<MaxLengthAttribute, string>(max => "maxlength=" + max.Length)
    });

    if (metadata.IsRequired)
    {
        attrs.Add("required");
    }

    string attrsHtml = String.Join(" ", attrs);
}
<input type=text id=@Html.IdForModel() @attrsHtml />
```

So you pass in an array of Delegates, and for each entry use a `Func<AttributeTypeGoesHere, string>`, and then return whatever HTML string you wanted for each attribute.

This actually decouples well - you can map only the attributes you care about, you can map different sets for different parts of the same HTML, and the final usage (like `@attrsHtml`) doesn't harm readability of the template.

Answer (score 2):

To do this you'll need to create your own HtmlHelper extension and use reflection to get at the attributes on the model property.  Look at the source code at http://codeplex.com/aspnet for the existing `...For()` HtmlHelper extensions.  You'll need to get the PropertyInfo object for the model property using the expression that is passed in as the argument.  They have several helper classes that should serve as templates for this.  Once you have that, use the GetCustomAttributes method on the PropertyInfo to find the StringLength attribute and extract it's value.  Since you'll be using a TagBuilder to create the input, add the length as an attribute via the TagBuilder.

```
   ...

   var attribute = propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringLengthAttribute),false)
                           .OfType<StringLengthAttribute>()
                           .FirstOrDefault();
   var length = attribute != null ? attribute.MaximumLength : 20; //provide a default
   builder.Attributes.Add("maxlength",length);

   ...

   return new MvcHtmlString( builder.ToString( TagRenderMode.SelfClosing ) );
}
```

<sub>See my comment on why I think this is a bad idea.</sub>

Comment: Ugh, this is a lot just so I can set the maxlength which validates your comment. This is for a mobile site so I was trying to cut down on all the validation markup & I'd prefer to have the maxlength value set regardless. I'll be using jQuery Mobile & Knockout.js, I'm still in process of piecing it together as I'm new to it all. At some point I may need to add additional attributes to the textbox due to Knockout so I thought this was the way to go. At this point I might just do straight HTML & revisit later. Unless you have suggestions?

Comment: You could use the existing helper if you were willing to supply some values manually.  `Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.PatientID, new { maxlength = 30, placeholder = "Patient ID" } );`

Comment: I still want the StringLength attribute on my property so I could validate it on the server correct? Which means Html.TextBoxFor would still render out the validation markup which I don't really want and I shouldn't need since maxlength is set correct? Is there a way to not have it render that out? If I am at the point of manually supplying a bunch of values & not using the validation is there much to gain by using Html.TextBoxFor over me writing the HTML myself?

Comment: @Billy - go to your web.config and turn off automatic validation in the client.  Note that the HtmlHelpers work with both model data AND the ViewDataDictionary, specifically providing *posted* values over *model* values when there are model errors detected on the server. Unless you want to replicate that, you're going to have people retyping everything when they've made a single model error.

Comment: @Billy - you might also want to check out using separate views for mobile vs. web via the mobile capable view engines, http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfTheWeek10NewMobileViewEnginesForASPNETMVC3SpeccompatibleWithASPNETMVC4.aspx.  You could simply omit or provide separate validation code in the mobile view.  You know that you don't have to include ValidationMessageFor, ValidationSummary, etc. in the view, right?

Comment: Thank you for the info, I was not aware of any of that. This clears up a few other questions I had as well about using the HtmlHelpers.

Answer (score 0):

An much simpler solution is to implement a custom `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` like this:

```
internal class CustomModelMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        ModelMetadata modelMetadata = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        var maxLengthAttribute = attributes.OfType<MaxLengthAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
        if (maxLengthAttribute != null)
        {
            modelMetadata.AdditionalValues.Add("maxLength", maxLengthAttribute.Length);
        }
        return modelMetadata;
    }
}
```

In the template you can simply use:

```
object maxLength;
ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.TryGetValue("maxLength", out maxLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

You **can** get the **StringLength** Validator from within an **Editor Template**, here are some examples:

https://jefferytay.wordpress.com/2011/12/20/asp-net-mvc-string-editor-template-which-handles-the-stringlength-attribute/

What I used and tested, as a result from the article above can be seen in my answer below (**tested with MVC 5**, EF 6) :

[ASP.NET MVC 3 - Data Annoation and Max Length/Size for Textbox Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231445/asp-net-mvc-3-data-annoation-and-max-length-size-for-textbox-rendering/29220870#29220870)

Without being specific, I've personally had some mixed results with attempts to implement some other approaches, and I don't find either claimed method particular long; however, I did think some of the other approached looked a little "prettier".

Answer (score 0):

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@model string
@{
    var htmlAttributes = ViewData["htmlAttributes"] ?? new { @class = "checkbox-inline" };

    var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);

    if (!attributes.ContainsKey("maxlength"))
    {
        var metadata = ViewData.ModelMetadata;
        var prop = metadata.ContainerType.GetProperty(metadata.PropertyName);
        var attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false);
        var maxLength = attrs.OfType<MaxLengthAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (maxLength != null)
        {
            attributes.Add("maxlength", maxLength.Length.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            var stringLength = attrs.OfType<StringLengthAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (stringLength != null)
            {
                attributes.Add("maxlength", stringLength.MaximumLength.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

}

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m, attributes)
```