# MVC5: Can @Html.TextBoxFor (or EditorFor) get its MaxLength from the Model's Data Annotation?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

It seems like there should be a way of specifying a Model annotation like:

```
[Display(Name="State")]
[MaxLength(2)]
public string State { get; set; }
```

so that when it is used in an EditorFor or TextBoxFor, like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.State)
```

or

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.State)
```

the generation of the html would set the input field's maxlength to 2.  Right now, I need to do this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.State, new { maxlength = 2 })
```

Since this violates the DRY principle, I'm wondering if there is already a built in way to have this flow from the data annotations to the input field?

Answer (score 4):

There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8112415/1043198) that describes a way to get hold of additional metadata values within the view. With this in mind, you can do something like this...

Annotate your model:

```
[AdditionalMetadata("MaxLength", 30)]
public string State { get; set; }
```

Define a custom editor template (String.cshtml):

```
@{
    string maxLength = ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("MaxLength")
        ? ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["MaxLength"].ToString() : null;
}

@Html.TextBox("", Model, new { maxlength = maxLength })
```

Then just do:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.State)
```

This might need some tweaking and could be improved by defining a custom attribute instead of just using `AdditionalMetadata` but it should get you started.

I tend to wrap up calls to the model's additional metadata in a custom HTML helper, too.

Comment: Wouldn't you still have to set this twice in data annotations?  Once to set the AdditionalMetadata and again to set the MaxLength or StringLength?  Granted, it would be a little more convenient since they would both be in the same file and I'll definitely give this a try.  Thanks for responding.

Comment: Yes, you would have to set it twice. Another thing to consider would be using a custom `ModelMetadataProvider` to look for the `MaxLength` attribute and explicitly add the `AdditionalValues` key if it's present, which will stop you from having to add two attributes every time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did to get around this.

Created a js file to handle adding in the required field marker and maxlength attribute:

```js
var formUtility = function () {
    return {
        AddMaxLength: function () {
            $("input[data-val-length-max]").each(function () {
                $(this).attr("maxlength", $(this).attr("data-val-length-max"));
            });
        },
        ShowRequiredFields: function () {
            $("input[data-val-required]").each(function () {
                $(this).prev().prepend("<span>* </span>");
            });
        }
    }
}();
```

After linking it on the page where I need it, just call it like this:

```js
    <script>
        formUtility.AddMaxLength();
        formUtility.ShowRequiredFields();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently supported, you can [vote for this feature](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1237).

I think by using `ContainerType` and `PropertyName` properties of `ModelMetadata` you can obtain the `PropertyInfo`, and from that query for the `MaxLength` attribute, all this in a custom editor template.

Comment: Not sure I like the idea of this becoming a "feature" as things like StringLengthAttribute and HTML maxlength are different concerns and this could introduce breaking changes into upgrading solutions... the templating system gives you plenty of flexibility to implement these constraints yourself; I don't see that it needs to be default behaviour.

Comment: @AntP you should comment on the issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[StringLength(2)]
```

instead of

```
[MaxLength(2)]
```