# How to better validate MaxLength in ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I really like declarative the client and server validation feature using model annotations on ASP.Net MVC, but I find the default behavior of notifying "you entered more than 125 character" quite annoying.

I mean, who's counting how many times to push backspace to get to 125?

What would be the right way to just stop accepting characters at (say) 125 using client validation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp

Comment: @MattBodily, thanks, I didn't state it well enough, to use that solution you have use the TextBoxFor (doesn't work with the EditorFor) helper and add the html attribute, and besides being too verbose it doesn't use the model annotation. Is there a way to generate the maxlength attribute from the model annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a custom `Editor Template` . there you have access to `annotations` applied to a property in `ViewData`, so you can use it to set textbox maxlength.

you can find a sample code here : 
[How to read property data annotation value in .NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112179/how-to-read-property-data-annotation-value-in-net-mvc)

Comment: Thanks that's it, I'm still wondering why dind't the MVC team do it this way right out of the box.Regards