# Dynamically Modify value of @Html.HtmlHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to modify a behavior for DataAttributes (Maxlength[int] or StringLength[int]), where it would add a "maxlength" attribute inside (textarea) tag  along with its "int" value. I have already performed some research, and the closest answers I obtained were [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301022/Creating-Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-MVC) and [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112179/how-to-read-property-data-annotation-value-in-net-mvc).

However, I hope to go one step further.

I already know that StringLength adds "data-val-length-max" and "data-val-length" attributes to the tag.
I spent a lot of time trying to implement solution in JavaScript unobtrusive validation file by using logic

```
if tag has data-val-length-max attribute 
    add maxlength attribute to this tag 
    assign its value equal to data-val-length-max value
```

However, in my project, Javascript files are constantly loaded/unloaded and it is extremely time-consuming to keep track of the logic flow, so I decided to change the approach, and try to implement it within C#.

Inside my .cshtml file, there are lines like following:

```
@Html.myLabelFor(model => model.Project.ProjectDescription, new { @title = "Enter a description for this project" })
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Project.ProjectDescription, new { @class = "textfield_Paragraph", @id = "ProjectDescription" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Project.ProjectDescription)
```

I learned that it successfully adds maxvalue if it adds @maxlength at the end:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Project.ProjectDescription, new { @class = "textfield_Paragraph", @id = "ProjectDescription", @maxlength = 50 })
```

However, I do not want to manually add @maxlenght this line to every TextAreaFor line in solution; I want to turn it into reusable code, that would dynamically perform such action to every variable within TextAreaFor inside the .cs file, which are marked like following:

```
[MaxLength(50)]
[Display(Name = "Project Description")]
public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
```

So I am thinking of implementing it by using the logic

```
if metadata has a MaxLength flag
    htmlAttributes += " ', @maxlength = ' + maxLengthValue"
```

So, physically it will still be

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Project.ProjectDescription, new { @class = "textfield_Paragraph", @id = "ProjectDescription" })
```

while the final value that will be loaded will be

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Project.ProjectDescription, new { @class = "textfield_Paragraph", @id = "ProjectDescription", @maxlength = 50 })
```

I want to know if something like this is even possible to implement, so I know beforehand if I should continue thinking in that direction.

Again, links I have posted above were the closest answers I could get, so I am curious if it is as far as I can get, or there is even more room to improve. My huge preference would be NOT touching .js files unless I absolutely HAVE to.